# check CRC32 in transport stream PAT section - C#

Tags: c#, parsing, packet, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

The question is how to check / regenerate crc32 PAT MPEG-TS table.

I have an array of bytes (Byte[] TS). All offset read normally. CRC32 I can not get. All algorithms do not give the correct result.

Comment: Could you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/blob/master/CSharp/DamienG.Library/Security/Cryptography/Crc32.cs
Where "DefaultPolynomial = 0xEDB88320;"
CALL CRC = crc32.ComputeHash(TS);

Answer (score 2):

The CRC Decoder Model specified in the Annex A of ISO/IEC 13818-1 is **MSB** (most significant bit first). The function in your link uses the default polynomial for Zip which is **LSB** (least significant bit first).

You must use `0x04C11DB7` for the polynomial instead of the reversed form `0xEDB88320`.

See the *Specification* and *Standards and common use* sections on the [Wikipedia CRC page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Specification).